# На Андроиде клавиатура сдвигает элементы сайта

Tags: android, html, xml

Здравствуйте. При заполнении формы на сайте, клавиатура, которая появилась, сдвигает элементы сайта верх и некоторые элементы вылезают поверх той самой формы. Я понял, что возможно это пофиксить с помощью XML, так как это происходит только на платформе Андроид, на iOS все нормально. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

За сдвиг элементов в android отвечаете `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` Поищите подобную строчку в манифесте, для вашего активити (как я понял WebView, сайт, открывается через какое-то активити или фрагмент). Попробуйте ее либо убрать, либо заменить на другую (перечень вариантов легко найдете)

Comment: У меня вообще нет AndroidManifest.xlm, да и в xlm я не смыслю нифига. У меня проблема, что клавиатура сдвигает элементы моего сайта на Андроид. Если есть возможность обойтись без xlm, то еще лучше. Я могу сам создать файл AndroidManifest.xlm и прописать там что нужно? Если да, то как правильно это сделать?

Comment: манифест для приложений только. Я неверно вас понял. Если у вас сайт открывается через браузер телефона и искажается, то вам нужно задавать вопросы по css, а не по android =)

Comment: Понял, спасибо.